# jQuery: How to extract data from a clicked HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dynamically generated forms. When a form is submitted I need jQuery to pick out certain pieces of information from the form that was clicked.

Right now, I am trying to use the `this` object which is generated after a click event. I am trying to extract the information from the `this` object because it appears to have the HTML values that I want. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Just get the field value like so:

```
var fieldValue = $('#field_id').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var name = $('#name').val();
```

Do it inside your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

After a click event, `this` should hold the DOM-element that was clicked. Assuming that element was inside a form, you can do this:

```
$(this).closest("form").serializeArray()
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mqe3u3oe/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below

`function get_value() {
var fieldValue = $('#field_id').val();
}`